# Counting messages per day (after 17:00 counts for next day)

Tags: mysql, sql, date, time

I have two MySQL tables: stats (left) and messages (right)

```
  +------------+---------+      +---------+------------+-----------+----------+
  |  _date     | msgcount|      | msg_id  | _date      | time      |  message |
  +------------+---------+      +----------------------+-----------+----------+
  | 2011-01-22 |  2      |      |   1     | 2011-01-22 |  06:23:11 | foo bar  |
  | 2011-01-23 |  4      |      |   2     | 2011-01-22 |  15:17:03 | baz      |
  | 2011-01-24 |  0      |      |   3     | 2011-01-22 |  17:05:45 | foobar   |
  | 2011-01-25 |  1      |      |   4     | 2011-01-22 |  23:58:13 | barbaz   |
  +------------+---------+      |   5     | 2011-01-23 |  00:06:32 | foo foo  |
                                |   6     | 2011-01-23 |  13:45:00 | bar foo  |
                                |   7     | 2011-01-25 |  02:22:34 | baz baz  |
                                +---------+------------+-----------+----------+
```

I filled in stats.msgcount, but in reality it is still empty. I'm looking for a query way to:

- count the number of messages for every stats._date (notice the zero msgcount on 2011-01-25)
- messages.time is in 24-hour format. All messages AFTER 5 o'clock (17:00:00) should be counted for the next day (notice msg_id 3 and 4 count for 2011-01-23)
- update stats.msgcount to hold all counts

I'm especially concerned about the "later than 17:00:00 count for next day" part. Is this possible in (My)SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

```
UPDATE stats LEFT JOIN
  ( SELECT date(addtime(_date,time) + interval 7 hour) as corrected_date, 
           count(*) as message_count
    FROM messages
    GROUP BY corrected_date ) mc
ON stats._date = mc.corrected_date
SET stats.msgcount = COALESCE( mc.message_count, 0 )
```

However this query requires dates you are interested in to be in the stats table already, if you don't have them make _date primary or unique key if its not yet and use:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO stats(_date,msgcount)
SELECT date(addtime(_date,time) + interval 7 hour) as corrected_date,
       count(*) as message_count
FROM messages
GROUP BY corrected_date
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! BTW - next to _date and time I also have a column with timestamp; would that be more efficient?

Comment: Only having corrected date in a column would speed it up - you could then use index on that column for grouping. It won't change much if you still need to add 7 hours or take date part of your timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

Really, all you're doing is shifting the times by 7 hours. Something like this should work:

```
UPDATE stats s
SET count = (SELECT COUNT(msg_id) FROM messages m
             WHERE m._date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(DATE_ADD(s._date, INTERVAL TIME_TO_SEC(m.time) SECOND), INTERVAL 7 HOUR)
                               AND DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(s._date, INTERVAL TIME_TO_SEC(m.time) SECOND), INTERVAL 17 HOUR));
```

The basic idea is that it takes each date in your stats table, adjusts it by 7 hours, and looks for messages sent in that range. If you used a DATETIME column instead of separate DATE and TIME columns, you wouldn't need the extra DATE_ADD(...,  TIME_TO_SEC) stuff.

There may be a better way to add a date and a time, I didn't see one with a quick look at the MySQL reference documents.

So all you'd need to do is insert a new row in the stats table with a 0 for the msgcount, and run the update command. If you only wanted to update a few days (since the message count probably isn't changing 6 days later) you just need a simple where clause on the update:

```
UPDATE stats s
SET ...
WHERE s._date BETWEEN '2012-04-03' AND '2012-04-08'
```

Comment: Yes, the table is as-is. There will be no (future) additions to the log. Second, if it would help, the messages table also has a timestamp column in it - perhaps this makes calculations easier?